# SoundManager2 and jQuery Dialog error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, soundmanager2

I have a strange problem.
I am using soundmanager2 library for playing notification sound.
It works all right until I make action(for example click on picture) which opens jQuery UI dialog.

After that sound doesn't play anymore.

Is it possible it makes some conflict or something?

Anyone has idea what could be wrong?

```
$( "#bigPhotoDialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: { my: "center top", at: "center top"},
    modal: true,
    minWidth: 630
});

$("#content").on('click', '.enlargePic', function() {

    var big = $(this).data("big");
    $("#bigPhotoDialog img").attr("src", big);
    $("#bigPhotoDialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: you'll need to post some code or the output of your browsers error console...

Comment: I posted my dialog code which is very simple and I dont think that's the problem.

Comment: Oh and btw there is no output in the console or anything. I think all exceptions are handles using catch statements.

Comment: did you try including the `debug-enabled` version of SM2? Adding `preventDefault()` to your click handler might also be worth a try...